# Как начать загрузку в qq.FileUploader после ctrl+V

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например, скопировал картинку, нажимаешь вставить и картинка внедряется в input type="file", но при этом не запускается qq.FileUploader, который отлично запускается, если выбрать файл. Код только вставки картинки из буфера обмена. Помогите запустить загрузку картинки через qq.FileUploader, пожалуйста!

`<input type="file" id="file_input">`

````
 
function pasteHandler(e) {
        let fileInputElement = document.getElementById('file_input');
        let container = new DataTransfer();
          if (e.clipboardData) {

          var items = e.clipboardData.items;
          if (items) {

             for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {

                   var blob = items[i].getAsFile();

                   var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                   var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);   
                    container.items.add(blob);
                }
             }
             fileInputElement.files = container.files;
             //здесь надо как-то запустить qq.FileUploader
          }
       } 
} ```

http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/ - qq.FileUploader

Заранее Вам спасибо!
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/ - здесь есть кнопка "upload a file". При выборе файла начинается процесс загрузки. Я пытаюсь вместо выбора файла, вставить картинку из буфера обмена. Как я достаю картинку из буфера обмена я написал в своём вопросе. Как работает qq.FileUpload написано по ссылке. 
По моему коду файл подставляется в input, но загрузка автоматически не начинается, а как её принудительно начать, я не разобрался, поэтому и прошу помочь.